# :Django forms - input boxes not rendering in template

Tags: python, django

I can't get my form to show up on my rendered template. The submit button is there but nothing else. I have two forms, one works fine its the `EstimateForm` I can't get to show.

**Edit: I forgot to mention the estimate form is part of the base template, in particular it's in the website footer. The contact template is extending the base template. The form in the base template is not showing up on any templates.** Sorry for not putting this information on at first.

This is the template

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="contact-form" style="margin-top: 25px">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ estimate_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="thm-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is what gets rendered

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="contact-form" style="margin-top: 25px" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="lfudMn6U8TBJ2czhZM4UZTINnP6xoLZs">

   <button type="submit" class="thm-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Forms. py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name*'}))
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email*'}))
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Phone Number*'}))
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your comments'})
    )


class EstimateForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name*'}))
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email*'}))
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Phone Number*'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BottomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_phone'].label = ""
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
                , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
                , '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get(
                'contact_phone'
                , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
             template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
               'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                      ['email'],
                      fail_silently=False)
        return redirect('/contact')
    return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })


def estimate(request):
form_class = EstimateForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = request.POST.get(
            'contact_name'
            , '')
        contact_email = request.POST.get(
            'contact_email'
            , '')
        contact_phone = request.POST.get(
            'contact_phone'
            , '')
        form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

        # Email the profile with the
        # contact information
        template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
        context = Context({
            'contact_name': contact_name,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'contact_phone': contact_phone,
            'form_content': form_content,
        })
        content = template.render(context)
        send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                  ['@gmail.com'],
                  fail_silently=False)
    return redirect('/contact')
return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
    'estimate': form_class,
})
```

Comment: in the view you define just `ContactForm` as `form_class`. But you doesn't define `estimate_form`, that is why you doesn't see it

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the form with key 'estimate'

```
return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
    'estimate': form_class,
})
```

But in template you are trying to access it by

```
{{ estimate_form.as_p }}
```

Just correct it to `{{ estimate.as_p }}`

Answer (score 0):

in the view you define just `ContactForm` as `form_class`. But you doesn't define `estimate_form`, that is why you doesn't see it.
so your view have to look like this:

```
def contact(request):
form_class = ContactForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = request.POST.get(
            'contact_name'
            , '')
        contact_email = request.POST.get(
            'contact_email'
            , '')
        contact_phone = request.POST.get(
            'contact_phone'
            , '')
        form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

        # Email the profile with the
        # contact information
         template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
        context = Context({
           'contact_name': contact_name,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'contact_phone': contact_phone,
            'form_content': form_content,
        })
        content = template.render(context)
        send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                  ['email'],
                  fail_silently=False)
    return redirect('/contact')
return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
    'form': form_class, 'estimate_form': estimate_form
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least four problems here, although not all of them are related to the issue you are asking about.

Firstly is that you pass the form class, rather than an instance, to the template. You need to instantiate the class first.

Secondly, you pass that into the template under the name `estimate`, but in the template you refer to it as `estimate_form`. You need to use the same name.

Thirdly, when the form is not valid, you don't pass the instantiated form with the errors back to the template, so the user will never know why it is not valid.

Fourth, when the form is valid you should get the data from `form.cleaned_data`, not directly from the POST.

Putting it all together:

```
def estimate(request):
    form_class = EstimateForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            contact_phone = form.cleaned_data['contact_phone']
            form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                      ['binford.blake@gmail.com'],
                      fail_silently=False)
        return redirect('/contact')
    else:
        form = form_class()
    return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
        'estimate_form': form,
    })
```

Comment: This did not work. I forgot to mention the estimate form is part of the base template, in particular it's in the website footer. The contact template is extending the base template. The form in the base template is not showing up on any templates. Sorry for not putting this information on at first.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You're going to need to post the full template and explain exactly what you are rendering and how.